# Создание и последующая css анимация элемента по клику

Tags: javascript, css, transition

Есть вот такой код:

```js
let icons = document.querySelectorAll(".icon") || [];
icons.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", clickIcon));

function clickIcon(event) {
 let myEvent = new Event("openMe");
 let page = document.createElement("div");
 page.style.position = "absolute";
 page.style.width = "100%";
 page.style.height = "100%";
 page.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
 page.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
 page.style["transform-origin"] = "0 0";
 page.style.transform = "scale(0)";
 page.style.transition =
  "transform 1s ease-out, left 1s ease-out, top 1s ease-out";
 document.querySelector("main").insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", page);
 page.addEventListener("openMe", openPage);
 page.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
}

function openPage() {
 let page = document.querySelector("main").lastElementChild;
 setTimeout(() => {
  page.style["background-color"] = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  page.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  page.style.left = 0;
  page.style.top = 0;
 }, 100);
};
```

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: sans;
}
body {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column nowrap;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

header {
 background-color: steelblue;
 padding: 10px;
}
main {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 background-color: #fff;
 position: relative;
}

.icon {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column nowrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 border-radius: 10%;
 position: relative;
 margin: 3vw;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 20vh;
 height: 20vh;
 background-color: brown;
}
footer {
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<header id="”pageHeader”">Header</header>
 <main>
  <div class="icon">Icon</span></div>
  <div class="icon">Icon</span></div>
  <div class="icon">Icon</span></div>
  <div class="icon">Icon</span></div>
  <div class="icon">Icon</span></div>
 </main>
 <footer>Copyright © 2020 Created by Dmitry Uchaikin</footer>
```

[Kод на CodePen](https://codepen.io/dmitry-7481/pen/VwvLyEd)

Задача: по клику на любой Icon, в координатах click (event.clientX, event.clientY), создаётся новый div с "transition: scale(0)", который сразу после этого должен плавно "открыться" до размеров родительского main. Т.е. его transition плавно изменяется на scale(1).
Всё работает прекрасно. Но только, если в JS коде, для запуска изменемия CSS transition, в строке 23, эти изменения обёрнуты в setTimeout 100ms. Если убрать setTimeout или уменьшать время до единиц милисекунд, **пропадает плавность**. В этом, собственно, проблема.
Я подозреваю, что пользовательское событие openMe срабатывает раньше, чем этот вновь созданный элемент вообще готов. Но это не точно. Я пробовал применить promise, но это результата не дало.

Comment: посмотри в сторону бутстрапа, либо другой библиотеки, их полно, ибо имхо выглядит не очень и анимация в синхронном коде на нативе(jquery посмотри) - нутакоэ

Comment: На счёт библиотек, наверное Вы правы. Я не "волшебник", я только учусь, поэтому хочу попросить Вас раскрыть немного тему "выглядит не очень". Очень поможете в освоении. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: @DmitryUchaikin мы про дизайн, мыя не дизанер да и ты наверное тоже. Я имел ввиду, что если использовать либы, то там уже отлаженный дизайн - который "нравится всем"

Comment: @Sevastopol' для этого знания нужны(я не говорю про автора, что афтар - плов), а то я видел как ажаксом загружали код-визуала(не помню, для инжекта вроде) в синхроне

Comment: @Sevastopol', благодарю за поддержку. Полностью согласен. Так и контроля больше, и лучше понимаешь что там происходит.

Comment: @Vadim, конечно. Вы правы. Есть много полезных библиотек. Но, вот хочется "свои песни" писать. Хочется повозится с основами. Залезть и разобраться с тем как это работает. Just for fun. © LT.

Comment: @DmitryUchaikin хотяб в асинхроне писал бы, тогда уж. [подробнее о "новых"(лето 2015) стандартах языка](https://habr.com/ru/post/305900/)
+ у jquery(++я бы его использовал, чтоб твою clickIcon превратить в 2 строки) есть "jquery ui", тоже посмотри

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два раза заверните в requestAnimationFrame:

```
function openPage() {
    let page = document.querySelector("main").lastElementChild;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          page.style["background-color"] = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
          page.style.transform = "scale(1)";
          page.style.left = 0;
          page.style.top = 0;
        });
    });
};
```

Вот здесь подробное объяснение похожей проблеммы: https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0?t=1233

Comment: Большое благодарю! Всё работает. И видео помогло понять что там происходит.